errors in flutter in vs code
The private field _web3Modal could be 'final'. Try making the field 'final'.dartprefer_final_fields Web3Modal _web3Modal Type: Web3Modal  package:w3m_flutter/main.dart The method 'connect' isn't defined for the type 'Web3Modal'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'connect'.dartundefined_method
Type: InvalidType
Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dartextra_positional_arguments_could_be_named
(new) Client Client()
package:http/src/client.dart
Creates a new platform appropriate client.
Creates an IOClient if dart:io is available and a BrowserClient if dart:js_interop is available, otherwise it will throw an unsupported error.
i am trying to integrate smart contract with flutter after run it show me metamask account after entering metamask sepolia eth adress .

Do you have any code references?
